# Bottleneck of Web server for static content only

Tags: single-page-application

I'm creating SPA using Vue with firestore as it's dB, because I don't wanna use firebase hosting, I'm using standard cheap webserver to host my spa instead.

Now in my understanding(which is not much) dynamic content like php always bottleneck in cpu/ram/etc. But if I only serve static content like in my case, what would be the bottleneck? And for estimation only, how many paralel user can the server handle at a time? (assuming it's the cheapest server, only 1 core, 1gb of ram etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, it's irrelevant now because I just found out about cloudflare pages, and it's free tier are perfect for me